# cant hit site on IIS 7.5 on server

Tags: iis-7.5

I have IIS 7.5 running on a server x. I would like to hit a website called Test that is running on this server x from a client pc. It works when i login into the server and run it from localhost.  When i go /Test it says file or directory not found? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Have you created a Virtual Directory in IIS for your site?  That should allow you to navigate.

Creating a Virtual Directory: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751432.aspx

Comment: Maybe check the Virtual Path for the Site in IIS?  It might be expecting something different than "/Test" from the browser request.